# Insufficient phone memory

Tags: backup

When I bought this phone Sony Experia CC51, I have more than ten apps, and now I uninstalled them one by one until they were all gone because it always said "Insufficient phone memory". I hope someone can help me solve this it as the phone always has insufficient memory when i try to download apps.

Thank you

Comment: You can take a look at Q/A under the tag [tag:insufficient-memory] on this website.

Answer (score 0):

Try to download and install SD maid in your device and clear your phone cache and reboot your device that should work

Comment: Could you mention a link for this app?

Comment: This is the download link of sd maid link:http://m.hiapphere.net/down/sd-maid-pro-%E2%80%93-system-cleaning-tool.             Cache cleaner apk link:http://www.appsapk.com/app-cache-cleaner/

Comment: @MatthewJob Thanks; but I already knew the link. My goal was for you to mention the link in the answer (not in the comment). Please edit and add it. Also, do the similar thing in this answer as well. http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/109605/how-do-i-get-room-in-memory-i-have-tryed-to-move-apps :)