# How do I get room in memory? I have tried to move apps

Tags: insufficient-memory

I have a 64gb SD card an my phones internal memory is full an it's not letting me download any more App's says I have insufficient space,  how do I fix tht i have 64gb. I should be able to download alot,  I've tryed unmounting sd card I moved couple apps to card n memory is still same plz help...

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall some useless app and clear your phone cache and download and install sd maid in your device and try to reebot your device after that try to download what application you want to download, if insufficient space is not poping up, comment me
 if work...